# Python Socket Makefile Error I/O operation on closed file

Tags: python, sockets, makefile, ioerror

I want to use socket.makefile method instead of socket.send or socket.recv but I face this error  I/O operation on closed file.

```
from socket import *

s = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('localhost',4321))
read = s.makefile('r',)
write = s.makefile('w')

def send(cmd):
    # print(cmd)
    write.write(cmd + '\n')
    write.flush()

with s,read,write:
    send('TEST')
    send('LIST')
    while True:
        send("DONE")
        data = read.readline()
        if not data: break
        item = data.strip()
        if item == 'DONE':
            break
        elif item.startswith("--player-"):
            print(f"player{item.split('--player-')[1]}")
        print(f'item: {item}')
    send('OTHER') 
send("GGGGGGGG")  #I want to send this part in another place .I dont want to in with s,read,write:
print(read.readline().strip())
```

Thanks for Help In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`with` statement has such behaviour:

```
with s,read,write:
    # smth to do
# <--------------- s, read and write are closed here
```

Therefore the subsequent send is invoked on closed object.

You need not use `with` statement:

```
# ...
send('TEST')
send('LIST')
while True:
    send("DONE")
    data = read.readline()
    if not data: break
    item = data.strip()
    if item == 'DONE':
        break
    elif item.startswith("--player-"):
        print(f"player{item.split('--player-')[1]}")
    print(f'item: {item}')
send('OTHER')
send("GGGGGGGG")  # write is open here
print(read.readline().strip())
```

Or recreate `write` and `read` files in another place. But at the same time, exclude the socket `s` from the first `with` so that the socket does not close.

```
with read, write:  # <-- s excluded
    send('TEST')
    send('LIST')
    while True:
        send("DONE")
        data = read.readline()
        if not data: break
        item = data.strip()
        if item == 'DONE':
            break
        elif item.startswith("--player-"):
            print(f"player{item.split('--player-')[1]}")
        print(f'item: {item}')
    send('OTHER')
# ...
read = s.makefile('r', )  # <-- recreate files
write = s.makefile('w')
send("GGGGGGGG")
```

Comment: Thank You very much